# FastCGI sent in stderr nginx , FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Trying to configure a old php website in nginx + fpm i see the following error

The nginx configuration is the following

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    root /var/www/html/example/public_html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com ;

    server_name server_IP_address;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example/example-chain.cer  ;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example/example.key;
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example_ssl_access;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example_ssl_error error;

        location / {

        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
```

And the code where the problem display is this

```
         $path =  parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY );
```

echo $path

Via web i see the following

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /var/www/html/example/public_html/newsroom/news.php on line 305
```

Also i did a print of the server variable and it display this:

```
Array
(
    [USER] => www-data
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5
    [HTTP_HOST] => example.com
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SERVER_NAME] => example.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 1.1.1.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 55388
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 2.2.2.2
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.12.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTPS] => on
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/2.0
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/html/example/public_html
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /newsroom/news.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /newsroom/news.php?news=289
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /newsroom/news.php
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => news=289
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/html/example/public_html/newsroom/news.php
    [PATH_INFO] => 
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /newsroom/news.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1519249027.5617
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1519249027
)
```

Any Idea or suggestion how i can troubleshoot this error?

thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like the browser doesn't send a referer. How do you access this site?

Comment: via browser, i am using local dns since the website is not yet live